# How can comments be removed from HTML files during an angular(js) build process?

Tags: angularjs

This should be straightforward - Is there a way to remove comments in HTML/view output during an angular build or render processes? The *goal* is simple - I don't want users to see them. I know this can be done with something like Grunt or Gulp, but want the comments to be visible during development (*and currently have Grunt for a build tool*). I've heard this can be done using the Angular CLI, which I know is for use in Angular >=2.0 projects, but am not sure if it could be using in a 1.x/JS project.

Comment: set grunt up to minify all your html and comments will be removed

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular 2+:

```
ng build --prod
```

creates the dist/ folder in the root. It contains via webpack stripped down code without any comments, at least with the standard configuration.

Comment: Sorry for only getting back now. Does this require Webpack? Doing a quick Google search, it appears that it does. Just want to confirm, as it would add good detail to this question.